# How to reload seeds in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In my environment, the seeds IP might change occasionaly.
On that situation, we would sometimes reload the seed settings in cassandra.yaml.
I saw the source on github the "nodetool reloadseeds " command is just developing now.

Is there any way to use the command in 3.9 environment easily?
When will the command will usually be released and which version?
Sorry, I am not sure at the manner of release schedule.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to reload seed information? AFAIK, once a node has joined the cluster the seed information is not required anymore because the node has learned the cluster topology via gossip.

Comment: IIRC, seed nodes are contacted more frequently by other nodes, so there is bigger chance of getting more up to date information

Comment: Thanks for your response. As if the nodes in seeds are not response, error messages are shown in logs. It is not good feeling..

Answer (score 1):

As part of [CASSANDRA-14190](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14190) the 2 new commands were added to `nodetool`: `getseeds` & `reloadseeds`, but they are only available in the upcoming version - 4.0 (the time frame for it isn't known yet).

Comment: Thanks for your response. OK, it could be used only in 4.0 Thanks.